# Two iframes(Different Sizes) side by side responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I'm trying to add a responsive layout with two iframes (Video(16:9) and Image(1:1)) side by side. Somehow I managed to search for a code that kind makes the layout responsive, the only problem that I'm facing right now is that I can't make the video to have the same height as the 2nd iframe has (image one), and at the same time to keep it's aspect ratio (16:9 since it's a youtube video).

What I have now (Demo w/ code): http://jsfiddle.net/dzw8jx4e/

HTML Code:

```
<div class="t_container">
  <div class="ts_iframe">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="250" width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jNQXAC9IVRw"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="tc_iframe">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="250" width="250" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0436/5985/3990/files/ezgif.com-video-to-gif.gif?v=1597626410"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.t_container{
    display: inline-table;
    width: 100%; 
    }
    .ts_iframe{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%; 
    }
    .tc_iframe{ 
    width: 250px;
    float:right;
    }

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .t_container { display: block; }
    .t_container .tc_iframe { display: block; width: 100%; float:none; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old way to keep aspect ratio is to use padding-top in percents, cause it will calculate it from available width. Here is an example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.t_container::after {
  clear: both;
}

.t_iframe {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.t_iframe iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.t_video {
  width: 64%;
  padding-top: 36%;
}

.t_image {
  width: 36%;
  padding-top: 36%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .t_iframe {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .t_video {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 36%;
  }

  .t_image {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="t_container">
  <div class="t_iframe t_video">
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jNQXAC9IVRw"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="t_iframe t_image">
    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0436/5985/3990/files/ezgif.com-video-to-gif.gif?v=1597626410"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/5sw1hedo/28/).

Answer (score 0):

if not for complex custom table logic (or maybe even then, given some flexbox experience), i'd recommend the flexbox display style for this kind of work. It's very optimized for responsiveness and dealing with some rough html edges automatically.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

You can gain a feeling for it with this game

https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Here is your code where i just removed any particular style related to table and kept only the `display: block` on the yt video to make them appear on different lines beyond the media query (note: this in flex is easier obtained by forcing `flex-direction: column` on the parent container)

http://jsfiddle.net/kctda2vr/1/

Cheers, let me know if something is missing.